# Creation of InstallAnywhere installer inside of Hudson CI

Tags: ant, automation, hudson, installanywhere

My company is trying to automate the creation of a nightly installer with Hudson.  Our license to install anywhere is running on a separate server.  We have an ANT build script set up to call the InstallAnywhere jar file which creates the installer automatically, and that works great when ran from the command prompt.

However when we try to run it inside of Hudson, Hudson is not able to connect to that license server.  InstallAnywhere spits out *The evaluation period has expired.*  Does anyone know what we can do to solve this issue?

I'm assuming it's a Hudson issue since our ANT script works fine when used outside of Hudson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that you need to set up some environment variables required by the InstallAnywhere process; I'm not very familiar with that product, but maybe it needs a home directory for the product, the location of the license file, the license key value, etc.

One easy way to debug this would be to check if Hudson is running under the same user that you are using to run the Ant script from the command line, then check the environment settings for the command line user if they are different.

Comment: Congrats! You were faster. It's usually the different user account issue.

Comment: A simple change of the user Hudson was running under fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm running Hudson as a service I had to use the "Default User" user. The solution was to copy the InstallAnywhere folder tree from "C:\Documents and Settings\MyUser" to "C:\Documents and Settings\Default User"

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, so I thought I would share my solution.  You can also register the CI build user so you can continue using the automated user rather than switching it to your own user account: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/downloads/instructions/productlicensing/en/InstallAnywhereProductLicensing.pdf#page=15

Set up a bat file to execute:

```
<PATH_TO_IA>\build.exe -registerNodeLocked <PATH_TO_IA>\License.lic
```

Note, the License will be your mac address.lic, and you only have to do this once.

My bat was:

```
C:\Progra~2\Instal~2\build.exe -registerNodeLocked C:\Progra~2\Instal~2\[MAC].lic
```

Then I added a bat task to jenkins, and ran the job:

[image]

You should see something like:

Trying to checkout IAEE version=12.0

InstallAnywhere is successfully registered.